# Center multiple images

Tags: image, center

Is there an effective CSS method to center multiple images?
The image on the link shows images aligned on the left, whereas I'm looking for method to center all three of them, so it looks that the images are under the text on the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYAs4.jpg)

Seen wrapper methods, seen align="center", seen display:block; 
Doesn't work in my case. The one that works is with center tag, but I find hand-coding every set of images with center tag time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You need `text-align:center` on the *container*.

Items can't center themselves without occupying the whole line, because that wouldn't make sense if there were any other not-centered-themselves items on the same line.